# Django chartjs multiple charts stacked

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates, chart.js

Hi I was creating a Django application where I use Chart.js to make a bar chart. I have a button that creates a random chart but when I hover over the newly generated chart the old one is still behind it. I suspect that it has something to do with my HTML canvas that is holding the chart but Im not sure. I only want one chart, the one that is created after clicking the button. I've tried clearing the rect for the canvas before drawing to it by using in this in JS.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

I am fairly new and am wondering if anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the chart is not destroying when you are simply doing `context.clearRect().`

If you look [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html) on the Chart.js website it says that you have to do `myLineChart.destroy();` in order to destroy a specific instance.

If you don't want to destroy it, I would assume that you can use `myLineChart.stop();` which stops animating the chart and then use `context.clearRect().` to clear the chart.